# Difficulty with error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Tags: javascript

I've been working on a JavaScript code in order to make a checkout cart of a pizza, but have been having an issue with the showCart function.

```
let pizzas=[
{ name:"Pepperoni", img:"pizza.png", price:8.99}, 
{ name:"Alfredo", img:"pizza.png", price:9.99}, 
{ name:"Cheese", img:"cheese.png", price:7.99} 
];

function registerButtonEvents() 
{
    let buttons=document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length-1; i++)
    {
        buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            addToCart(i);
        });
    }
    let number = localStorage.getItem("number");
    if(number == null)
        number = 0;
    document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = number;
}

function addToCart(pId)
{
    let cartJ = localStorage.getItem("cart");
    let cart;

    if(cartJ===null) //Cart is empty
    {
        cart=[];
    }
    else
    {
        cart=cartJ.split(",");
    }

    cart.push(pId);
    let number= localStorage.getItem("number");

    if(number===null)
        number = 0;

    document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = `${++number}`;
    localStorage.setItem("cart", cart.toString());
    localStorage.setItem("number", number);
}

function clearCart()
{
    localStorage.removeItem("cart");
    localStorage.removeItem("num");
}

function showCart() 
{
    let cartJ = localStorage.getItem("cart");
    let cart = [];
    let info = "";
    if(cartJ === null)
    {
        document.getElementById("myCart").innerHTML=`<h2>No items in cart!</h2>`;
    }
    else
    {
        cart = cartJ.split(","); 
        for (let i in cart)
        {
            let item = pizzas[cart[i]];
            info+=
                `<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                        <h3>${item.name}</h3>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                        <img class="pizza" src="./images/${item.img}" alt="pepperoni">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                        <h3>${item.price}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="removePizza(${i})">Remove</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                `;
        }
        document.getElementById("myCart").innerHTML=info;
    }
}


function removePizza(piz)
{
    var cart = localStorage.getItem("cart");
    cart = cart.split(",");
    cart.splice(piz, 1);
    if (cart.length == 0)
        clearCart();
    else
    {
        localStorage.setItem("cart", cart);
        localStorage.setItem("number",cart.length);
    }
    showCart();
}
```

Developer tools tell me that the error is in the line in:

```
let item = pizzas[cart[i]];
```

but I don't necessarily understand why. If anyone could send some feedback it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In this situation you should probably make a fiddle on jsfiddle.net or use the stackoverflow snippet example to provide a working demonstration of the problem. That said, it looks like you're trying to access a property on an undefined variable. If the variable is undefined there is no property and your javascript falls over.

Comment: Use Stack Snippets!! Links rot, and become useless over time.

Comment: For a possible hint to your problem, when the error is thrown, what is the value of the i property? You're looping over the properties of the array which includes properties like 'length'. I think the problem is cart doesn't have an object called length and so on. Change your loop to a regular iterative for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is when you access `<h3>${item.name}</h3>`. Your item is undefined there because your cart (`cart = cartJ.split(",");`) probably stores some strings like "Pepperoni" (as you split them using a comma) and after that you want to access the pizzas array using one of those strings instead of an index.

[image: Pizzas]